# Registering a Midi Device in Modern Kernel Versions

Tags: c, linux-kernel, driver, linux-device-driver, libalsa

I am currently writing a Linux Kernel module that will create a virtual Midi device so that a user-space program can send midi signals to any DAW-like software. I found a [wonderful function](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/driver-api/sound.html#c.register_sound_midi) to help me in my task: `int register_sound_midi(const struct file_operations * fops, int dev)`. The problem is that this function ceased to exist after Kernel Version 4.15. From [V15](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15.18/source/include/linux/sound.h) to [V16](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.16/source/include/linux/sound.h) the register and unregister functions just disappear. I'm now dumbfounded on how to register a fake midi device from the kernel in versions post 4.15. How can I register a midi device in versions of Kernel post 4.15? Is it possible to make the module backwards compatible with older kernel versions?

Current Code:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/sound.h>
#include <sound/core.h>


MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Module to create dummy midi devices.");
MODULE_VERSION("0.01");

static int dummy_midi_open(struct inode *, struct file *);
static int dummy_midi_release(struct inode *, struct file *);
static ssize_t dummy_midi_read(struct file *, char *, size_t, loff_t *);
static ssize_t dummy_midi_write(struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t *);

static struct file_operations dummy_midi_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .read = dummy_midi_read,
    .write = dummy_midi_write,
    .open = dummy_midi_open,
    .release = dummy_midi_release
};

static int minor;

static int dummy_midi_open(struct inode *midi_inode, struct file *midi_file)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO"Open\n");
    return 0;
}

static int dummy_midi_release(struct inode *midi_inode, struct file *midi_file)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO"Release\n");
        return 0;
}

static ssize_t dummy_midi_read(struct file *filp, char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO"Read\n");
    return 0;
}

static ssize_t dummy_midi_write(struct file *filp, const char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO"Write\n");
        return 0;
}


static int __init midimodule_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO"Initializing Module\n");
    minor = register_sound_midi(&dummy_midi_fops,-1);
    printk(KERN_INFO"Registered MIDI Device: %d\n",minor);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit midimodule_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO"Leaving now\n");
    unregister_sound_midi(minor);
    printk(KERN_INFO"Unregistered MIDI Device: %d\n",minor);
}

module_init(midimodule_init);
module_exit(midimodule_exit);
```

Comment: It seems is was ripped out as part of the removal of OSS (Open Sound System) from the kernel. I don't know much about sound drivers, but could you use the existing "virmidi" driver as described in [HOWTO Use MIDI Sequencers With Softsynths](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/MIDI-HOWTO-10.html)?

Comment: The source for the "virmidi" driver is in "sound/drivers/virmidi.c" in the kernel source. Perhaps it will help you write your own driver.